# How do I pass dynamic keys into a object described by an interface?

Tags: typescript

I have a fairly straight forward json object, that has two distinct keys "checked" and "unchecked".

```
{
  "checked" : {
    "trClass": ",
    "text": "Select all",
    "icon": "fa fa-square-o"
  },
  "unchecked": {
    "trClass": "success",
    "text": "Deselect all",
    "icon": "fa fa-check-square"
  }
}
```

I have described this object as follows:

```
interface CheckProps {
  trClass: string;
  test: string;
  icon: string;
}
interface CheckJson {
  checked: CheckProps;
  unchecked: CheckProps;
}
```

Now, in my code the key "checked" or "unchecked" will be passed in dynamically, and I keep getting a **"implicit has any type"** error. the $button element has a data attribute called "state" that will either be 'checked' or 'unchecked' so it will be a valid selector, but how do I tell TypeScript this?

Here is the code in question:

```
function toggleAllCheckableRows(e: JQueryEventObject){
  const $button: JQuery = $(e.target);
  const json: CheckJson = $button.data('json');
  const state: string = $button.data('state');
  const oppositeSelector: string = $button.data('state') === 'checked' ? 'unchecked' : 'checked';

  const currentState = json[state]; //Elementy immplicity has 'any' type because type 'CheckJson' has no index signature
  const oppositeState = json[oppositeSelector]; //Elementy immplicity has 'any' type because type 'CheckJson' has no index signature
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
interface CheckJson {
  checked: CheckProps;
  unchecked: CheckProps;
}

const oppositeSelector = Math.random() % 2 > 0 ? 'unchecked' : 'checked';

declare const json: CheckJson;
json[oppositeSelector];
```

Not that the reason you received that error is because you used a pointless, unnecessary type annotation on `oppositeSelector`. You said it was a `string`, but the compiler infers the type as `'checked' | 'unchecked'`.

Let the compiler do its job and avoid annotating variables that have initializers unless you get a `--noImplicitAny` error. In that case only add the type annotations necessary to correct the specific error.
By annotating everything, we fail to take advantage of some of TypeScript's most critical benefits.

Now for the `state` variable

```
const state: string = $button.data('state');
```

`$.fn.data` has a return type of `any` so we could change the annotation to `'checked' | 'unchecked'`,

```
const state: 'checked' | 'unchecked' = $button.data('state');
```

but that is not the most readable as it is verbose and it also doesn't make the assignment from `any` explicit.

To make it clear what is going on, we could write

```
const state = <'checked' | 'unchecked'>$button.data('state');
```

which is clearer but still awkward.

Still we can do better by declaring the type of the value returned by `.`date('state')`

```
interface JQuery {
  data(key: 'state'): 'checked' | 'unchecked';
}

const state = $button.data('state');
```

*Thank you, kimamula, for your correct and helpful comments*

Comment: Also, `state` should be explicitly declared as `'checked' | 'unchecked'`.

Comment: No it should note. Let the compiler infer the type.

Comment: Then how can TypeScript infer `$button.data('state')` as `checked' | 'unchecked`?

Comment: It knows because of the type of the initializer. This works for `const` bindings particularly well. Of course the OP made this `const` because it does not change.

Comment: Sorry, my fault. The return type of `JQuery.data()` is `any`, therefore it compiles without declaring the type of `state` explicitly. https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/jquery/index.d.ts#L1866

Comment: No that is not why. You do not need to declare the type explicitly. It infers `'checked' | 'unchecked'` because of the ternary operator. `any` is not a factor. See here: http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=const%20oppositeSelector%20%3D%20Math.random()%20%25%202%20%3E%200%20%3F%20%20'unchecked'%20%3A%20'checked'%3B

Comment: I understand the type of `Math.random() % 2 > 0 ?  'unchecked' : 'checked'` is `'checked' | 'unchecked'`. However, the type of `state` which is initialized with `$button.data('state');` in the original question, is `any.`

Comment: This infers `'checked' | 'unchecked'` `const oppositeSelector = (1 as any) ?  'unchecked' : 'checked';` Putting types on local variables is a bad practice most of the time.

Comment: Please look this. https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20CheckProps%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20trClass%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20test%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20icon%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Ainterface%20CheckJson%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20checked%3A%20CheckProps%3B%0D%0A%20%20unchecked%3A%20CheckProps%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Adeclare%20const%20json%3A%20CheckJson%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Adeclare%20const%20%24button%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20data(key%3A%20string)%3A%20any%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20state%20%3D%20%24button.data('state')%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20currentState%20%3D%20json%5Bstate%5D%3B

Comment: Right, but I am talking about the `oppositeSelector` variable.

Comment: With `noImplicitAny` option, the above link results in a compilation error. Therefore, `state` should be explicitly declared as `'checked' | 'unchecked'`.

Comment: Sorry, I was thinking of `oppositeSelector`. State is used oddly.

Comment: Yes, I totally agree with `oppositeSelector` should not be explicitly declared as `'checked' | 'unchecked'`!

Comment: Sorry for confusion :). Much going on at once. I got riled up because the bug was so subtle in the OP. He added a needless type and it caused his code to break. Then I missed your point.

Comment: @AluanHaddad Two things. 1. I removed the type annotation on oppositeSelector, and that error is gone. This is TypeScript awesomeness I didn't even realize! It's smart enough to figure it out! 2. The same thing cannot be done for my state variable. It does not know that $button.data('state') will be 'checked' or 'unchecked'.

Comment: @Amir thank you for your comment, I have updated the answer to cover alternatives including explicit annotation

Comment: @AluanHaddad thank you so much for the detailed answer!